# Working on permuted monad transformer stack

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

One of the problems with monad transformers I find is the need to `lift` the operations into the right monad. A single `lift` here and there isn't bad, but sometimes there are functions that looks like this:

```
fun = do
  lift a
  lift b
  c
  lift d
  lift e
  f
```

I would like to be able to write this function thus:

```
fun = monadInvert $ do
  a
  b
  lift c
  d
  e
  lift f
```

This halves the number of `lift`s and makes the code cleaner.

The question is: for what monads is `monadInvert` possible? How should one create this function?

Bonus points: define it for `monad m` which is an instance of `MonadIO`.

The title of this question speaks of permutations: indeed, how can we deal with arbitrary permutations of a monad tranformer stack?

Comment: I highly doubt you can (but perhaps some evil trickery can be used). Thinking about the types just doesn't add up to me.

Comment: Not really a shovel-ready solution, but you might find [this paper](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mwh/papers/monadic.pdf) worth reading; from the abstract: "our algorithm inserts the necessary binds, units, and monad-to-monad morphisms so that the program type checks"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be interested in [Monads, Zippers and Views, Virtualizing the Monad Stack](http://users.ugent.be/~tschrijv/Research/papers/monads_zippers_views.pdf) by Tom Schrijvers and Bruno Oliveira.

This doesn't address your point about reducing the lifts, but it's an interesting approach to your "monad permutations" problem.

Here's the abstract:

> This work aims at making monadic components more reusable and robust
>   to changes by employing two new techniques for virtualizing the monad
>   stack: the monad zipper and monad views. The monad zipper is a monad
>   transformer that creates virtual monad stacks by ignoring particular
>   layers in a concrete stack. Monad views provide a general framework
>   for monad stack virtualization: they take the monad zipper one step
>   further and integrate it with a wide range of other virtualizations.
>   For instance, particular views allow restricted access to monads in
>   the stack. Furthermore, monad views can be used by components to
>   provide a call-by-reference-like mechanism to access particular layers
>   of the monad stack. With these two mechanisms component requirements
>   in terms of the monad stack shape no longer need to be literally
>   reflected in the concrete monad stack, making these components more
>   reusable and robust to changes.

Answer (score 16):

Well, first of all, you don't actually need so much lifting.  For monad transformers the following identities hold:

```
lift c >>= lift . f = lift (c >>= f)
lift c1 >> lift c2  = lift (c1 >> c2)
```

It's not uncommon to write:

```
x <- lift $ do
    {- ... -}
```

Next is:  When you use libraries like *mtl* or *monadLib* (i.e. type class based libraries instead of *transformers* directly), you actually can access most underlying monads directly:

```
c :: StateT MyState (ReaderT MyConfig SomeOtherMonad) Result
c = do
    x <- ask
    y <- get
    {- ... -}
```

Finally, if you really need a lot of lifting despite these two points, you should consider writing a custom monad or even use an entirely different abstraction.  I find myself using the automaton arrow for stateful computations instead of a state monad.

Comment: Not really a solution, but thanks anyway. Note that I can't write `lift (a >> b >> c)`, because a,b,c are from two different monads.

Answer (score 1):

I am mostly sure that what you are decribing is impossible for IO, which is always the innermost monad:

From Martin Grabmüller: Monad Transformers Step by Step, available at
http://www.grabmueller.de/martin/www/pub/

> Down in this document, we call liftIO in eval6 to perform I/O actions.
>   Why do we need to lift in this case? Because there is no IO class for
>   which we can instantiate a type as. Therefore, for I/O actions, we
>   have to call lift to send the commands inwards

In general, for monads less restrictive than IO, (such as Error and State) order still matters for semantics, so you can't change the order of the stack just to make syntax more convenient.

For some monads, like Reader, that are central (in that they do commute in the stack), your idea seems not clearly impossible. I don't know how to write it though. I guess it would be a type class `CentralMonad` that `ReaderT` is an instance of, with some implementation...